# Git: Parent repo references an old revision of its submodule - how to change?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I have a Git repo parent (P) with a submodule (S). Locally everything is fine, both P and S are up to date, however in remote repo (GitLab) I can see parent repo is somehow stuck on old revision of my submodule, it looks like this:

```
my_submodule @hash //hash is few weeks old
```

How did it happen? How to change remote parent repo to reference latest commit?

I've found a [very similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535953/how-to-update-commit-hash-in-parent-repo-of-submodule), but answer does not work for me.

Comment: `very similar problem here, but answer does not work for me.` Did you do the first part "After commiting in the submodule"?

Answer (score 0):

> How did it happen?

Is it expected - submodule reference *specific commit*.

> How to change remote parent repo to reference latest commit?

Clone parent repo, `cd submodule`, maybe `git checkout master`, then `git pull`, then `cd ..` and `git add submodule` and `git commit -m "Update submodule revision"`.

Submodule tracks *specific commit* of the submodule. Updating the commit of a submodule is a normal commit in the parent.

Comment: Don't forget `git push` in the superproject.